# how to set image text after the till calender section

Tags: html, css

I want to set image text after the **till(calender)**

like this:-
[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label><strong>Erbjudande</strong></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label><strong>Tillgangligt</strong></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label><small>Laddsuppfill</small></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label><small>Fran</small></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label><small>Till</small></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <small><input type="file" /></small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <small><input type="date" placeholder="2020-05-21"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <small><input type="date" placeholder="2020-05-21"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> **//here I am facing issue //here I am trying to set image text after the till calender**
                Image
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <br />


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label><strong>Antal</strong></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label><strong>Giltigt</strong></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label><small>Ange antial</small></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label><small>Fran</small></label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label><small>Till</small></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <small><input type="text" placeholder="600" style="width:100px" /></small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <small><input type="date" placeholder="2020-05-21"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <small><input type="date" placeholder="2020-05-21"></small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <button type="button">Avsluta</button>
                <button type="button">Redigera</button>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label>status</label><strong>Aktiv</strong>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @*here copy same above whole content left side*@
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @*here copy same above whole content right botom side*@
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @*here copy same above whole content left botom  side*@
    </div>
</div>
```

what I am trying see below code I am continuously divide a partision but image text not set after the till calender section

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <small><input type="file" /></small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <small><input type="date" placeholder="2020-05-21"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <small><input type="date" placeholder="2020-05-21"></small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> **//here I am facing issue //here I am trying to set image text after the till calender**
                Image
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying bootstrap partion like(4 3 3 2) and(4 4 3 1) but not work

I want to add image text after the till calender see image please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The columns in that specific row are not indeed `4` `4` `3` `1`, but `4` `4` `4` `1`.

I'm sure you just overlooked it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <small><input type="file" /></small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <small><input type="date" placeholder="2020-05-21"></small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <small><input type="date" placeholder="2020-05-21"></small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"> **//here I am facing issue //here I am trying to set image text after the till calender**
        Image
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I fixed it.

Comment: sorry I am trying and trying before upload the question now issue is solved

Comment: @AayushiBabariya. Haha, no shame. Happens to me all the time.

Comment: I want to add the border on that block because I have 4 block can you help more please

Comment: @AayushiBabariya. What do you mean, a border on that row? Just add `style="border: solid 1px #000"` (the syntax is style="border: [border-style] [width] [color]") on whatever block you want it. E.g. `<div class="row" style="...">`

Comment: What do you mean, a border on that row? No

Answer (score 1):

**Bootstrap `cols` can max be divided in `12` parts. -> `12 = full width`**

**You are trying `4 4 4 1` = `13` so you get**

`4 4 4`

`1`

**You should try something that sums up to 12. like below**

`4 4 3 1` or `3 3 3 3`

**if sum exceeds 12, it will get on next line.**